# Google Script AddRecord Function and For Loops

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a for loop using Google Script and having a hard time with adding records. When I add a record, I receive one's email and then 36 questions as such:

```
function AddRecord(email, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30, q31, q32, q33, q34, q35, q36){
var url ="Name of Url";
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
ws.appendRow([email, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30, q31, q32, q33, q34, q35, q36]);}
```

---

I would think the code below would allow me to pass this function correctly by the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). I have tried different things but I am confused with how to proceed dealing with parameters/arrays/etc. **How would I go about creating a for loop for this?**

```
const questions = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
    questions.push(`q${i}`);
}
function AddRecord(email, ... questions){
var url ="Name of Url";
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
ws.appendRow([email, ... questions]);}
```

Comment: I think just using the spread operator once in  the appendRow would might work.  But I wasn't getting the code fragment to work outside of a function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function AddRecord(email, questions) {
  var url = "Name of Url";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  questions.unshift(email)
  ws.appendRow(questions);
}
```

I had to do this to test it.

```
function AddRecord() {
  const email = 'email';
  const questions = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 36; i++) { questions.push(`q${i}`); }
  var id = gobj.globals.testsourceid;//I have this id in globals
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);//so I went with openById()
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  questions.unshift(email)
  ws.appendRow(questions);
}
```

Testing it this way is much better:

```
function testAddRecord() {
  const email = 'email';
  const questions = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 36; i++) { questions.push(`q${i}`); }
  AddRecord(email, questions);
}
function AddRecord(email, questions) {
  var id = gobj.globals.testsourceid;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  questions.unshift(email)
  ws.appendRow(questions);
}
```

output:

| email | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6 | q7 | q8 | q9 | q10 | q11 | q12 | q13 | q14 | q15 | q16 | q17 | q18 | q19 | q20 | q21 | q22 | q23 | q24 | q25 | q26 | q27 | q28 | q29 | q30 | q31 | q32 | q33 | q34 | q35 | q36 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: In my index.html file, I call q1 a specific input that the user types (i.e. so it is not called q1 but something else like A). I do this in my index.html file by running the following google.script.run.AddRecord(q1, q2, q3, q4, ..., q36); Is there anyway to add what the user has typed here in the above script instead of adding the words email, q1, ..., q36 for the appended row. This answer was very helpful. I appreciate your time with this, and I am curious how to do that.

Comment: I tried declaring the constants instead as variables and sadly that didn't work.

Comment: I'd need to see your index.html file

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GR5OZQMIDKZG

Comment: Wow, I'd hate to enter data in that.  I'd rather separate them with delimiters.

Comment: I'm getting malformed html content error so personally I don't want to mess with it.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. I'll mess around with it some more. The index file doesn't look exactly like that as I wanted to just include the part that is relevant to this question.